# c# selenium internet explorer timeout

Tags: c#, selenium

I am having timeout issues late into my selenium test when calling driver.WindowHandles.

I want to **increase the timeout default of 60 seconds in the IE driver.**

error message;

```
ex = {"The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:43196/session/3385234a-4378-419a-9e3a-c59e6b0f7913/window timed out after 60 seconds."}
```

Comment: This is not a very clear question.  you should share more information.  Like, what does `binary` equate to, and wether you are using iedriver.exe, or `firefoxdriver.exe` etc.

Comment: I am only trying to increase the default timeout for the IE driver.

Comment: so why are you instantiating `FirefoxDriver` and not `InternetExplorerDriver`

Comment: Im not I was just using it as an example, I am removing the firefox driver code as it is too confusing.

Answer (score 1):

it was rather simple to increase the timespan of requests

```
InternetExplorerDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"c:\path", options, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
```